# Invertible matrix and induction

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, induction

Observe the real matrices

$$
    B = \begin{pmatrix}
    4 & 2  \\
    -6 & -3 \\
    \end{pmatrix}, \
    C = \begin{pmatrix}
    -3 & -2  \\
    6 & 4 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$ 
in $Mat_2(\mathbb{R})$. Let $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ be a real number and let: 
$$ A =\alpha \cdot B+C\in Mat_2(\mathbb{R})$$

Find the real values of $\alpha$ where A is invertible and prove by induction in $n$ that for all integers $n\ge 1$ it is true that 
$$ A^n = \alpha{^n}\cdot B+C$$

---

I know that A is invertible if $det(A) \ne 0 $, so in order to find the real values $\alpha$ would it be possible to add the two matrices $\alpha \cdot B$ and $C$ together and find the determinant?

I am unsure how to do the proof by induction part of the question.

Comment: It is possible to add matrices and compute determinants. What do you get when you do that.

Comment: det(A) = (4$\alpha$ - 3)(-3$\alpha$ +4) - (-6$\alpha$ +6)(2$\alpha$ -2) =  -12$\alpha$^2+16$\alpha$+9$\alpha$-12+12$\alpha$^2+12$\alpha$+12$\alpha$-12 = $\alpha$ 
So when $\alpha \ne 0 $ Matrix A is invertible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $B^2=B$, that $C^2=C$, and that $BC=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$. Therefore,$$(\alpha B+C)^n=\alpha^nB^n+C^n=\alpha^nB+C.$$On the other hand, an easy computation show that $\det\left(\alpha B+C\right)=\alpha$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Thank you. I've edited my answer.

Comment: So there is no need to do a formal proof by induction, when you observe that the matrices B and C are commute?

Comment: @MadsJeppesen No, there isn't. But notice that, besides using the fact that they commute, I used the fact that their product is $0$.